# Create a simple Caeser Cipher in Java

Tags: java

I need to create a cipher that will take a string from the user and a shift number that will change the character in the string and shift it the number the user entered.  This is a project for one of my classes and I am stuck on what I am doing wrong.  We have to do it with out using an array and have to use the constants declared at the beginning.  Basically we can use what I already have within my code.  I haven't finished the `decrypt` section.  But that method should just revert the `encrypted` code back to the original.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CaesarCipher {

public static final String UPPER_ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
public static final String LOWER_ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
public static final String DIGITS = "0123456789";

public static String encrypt ( String plainText , int shift ) {

  String cipherText = "";

  for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {

    char c = plainText.charAt(i); 

    int newShift = UPPER_ALPHABET.indexOf(c) + shift;

    if (newShift < 0) {
      newShift += 26;
    } 
    else if (newShift > 25) {
      int remainder = newShift % 25;
    } 
    else if (newShift >= 0 && newShift < 26) {  
      newShift = newShift;
    }         
    newShift = UPPER_ALPHABET.indexOf(c) + shift;
    cipherText += UPPER_ALPHABET.charAt(newShift);
  }   
  for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {

    char c = plainText.charAt(i); 

    int newShift = LOWER_ALPHABET.indexOf(c) + shift;

    if (newShift < 0) {
      newShift += 26;
    } 
    else if (newShift > 25) {
      int remainder = newShift % 25;
    } 
    else if (newShift >= 0 && newShift < 26) {  
      newShift = newShift;
    }         
    newShift = LOWER_ALPHABET.indexOf(c) + shift;
    cipherText += LOWER_ALPHABET.charAt(newShift);
  }    
  for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {

    char c = plainText.charAt(i); 

    int newShift = DIGITS.indexOf(c) + shift;

    if (newShift < 0) {
      newShift += 26;
    } 
    else if (newShift > 25) {
      int remainder = newShift % 25;
    } 
    else if (newShift >= 0 && newShift < 26) {  
      newShift = newShift;
    }         
    newShift = DIGITS.indexOf(c) + shift;
    cipherText += DIGITS.charAt(newShift);
  } 
  //System.out.println(cipherText);
  return cipherText;
}

//public static String decrypt ( String cipherText , int shift ) {   
//  System.out.println(cipherText);
//  return cipherText;
//}

public static void main(String[] args) {   

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter the String for Encryption: ");
  String plainText = input.next();


  System.out.println("Enter a positive interger between 0 and 25 to create our CeasarCipher");
  int shift = input.nextInt();

  if (shift < 0 || shift > 25) {
    System.out.println("Don't be a jerk ... follow directions!");
    System.exit(0);
  }
  else {
    encrypt(plainText, shift);     
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: `else if (newShift >= 0 && newShift < 26) {  
      newShift = newShift;
    }` What is this code? Why are you setting `newShift` equal to itself? Please clean this code up before asking for help.

Comment: I want `newShift` to stay the same in that `else if` condition.  That is why.  If you don't have any input that is beneficial please refrain from commenting.

Comment: Can you include some examples of input/expected output/actual output in the post? Also, in fa few places you have "int remainder = newShift % 25;" - what's the purpose of this code? Right now you're not actually doing anything with the value.

Comment: I actually have to agree with @nhouser9 about the "newShift = newShift" being unnecessary. Also, right now you're doing the exact same thing 3 times in a row, the main difference being the input. You can reduce the length of this code by 2/3 by figuring out in advance whether it's an uppercase letter, lowercase letter, or digit and selecting from the list accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code goes about this problem the wrong way.  You treat every character as if it's uppercase, then lowercase, then a digit, augmenting the cipher text with three conversions for every character.  You don't bother to test the result of `.indexOf()` to see if it wasn't in the character set before you shift it.  You don't handle punctuation correctly (pass it through). Your modular arithmetic is off in several places and your `main()` routine doesn't read in lines of text correctly.

The problem is simpler than you're making it.  Working within the constraints presented, here's a rewrite of your code that encrypts the text:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CaesarCipher {

    public static final String UPPER_ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public static final String LOWER_ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public static final String DIGITS = "0123456789";

    public static String encrypt (String plainText, int shift) {

        String cipherText = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length(); i++) {

            char c = plainText.charAt(i);

            String alphabet = null;

            if (UPPER_ALPHABET.indexOf(c) > -1) {
                alphabet = UPPER_ALPHABET;
            } else if (LOWER_ALPHABET.indexOf(c) > -1) {
                alphabet = LOWER_ALPHABET;
            } else if (DIGITS.indexOf(c) > -1) {
                alphabet = DIGITS;
            }

            if (alphabet != null) {
                int length = alphabet.length();

                c += shift;

                while (c > alphabet.charAt(length - 1)) {
                    c -= length;
                }
            }

            cipherText += c;
        }

        return cipherText;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the String for Encryption: ");
        String plainText = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Enter a positive integer between 0 and 25 to create our CeasarCipher: ");
        int shift = input.nextInt();

        if (shift < 0 || shift > 25) {
            System.out.println("Don't be a jerk ... follow directions!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        System.out.println(encrypt(plainText, shift));
    } 
}
```

The `decrypt` method can be derived via trivial modifications to the `encrypt` method.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with cdlane's answer but have a few points to add as well. Three general things on refactoring:

- Don't have "if" statements that do nothing (such as the one assigning newShift to itself)
- Use the DRY principal (Don't Repeat Yourself). If you do a nearly identical procedure several times in a row, you almost certainly either have a mistake in your algorithm or need to refactor. In this case, you could just test to see which alphabet to use "up front" like cdlane does in his example.
- Only create values that you intend to use. For example, you never use the value `int remainder = newShift % 25;`, which could either indicate a bug or incomplete code section (if you intended to use it but forgot) or a need to refactor/clean up your code.

Here's one possible implementation (written in C# rather than Java but there's not much of a difference). I haven't been able to test it quite as thoroughly as I'd like, and it only works for lowercase letters, but it can be modified to handle other input types as well:

```
public string CaesarCypher(string toEncode, int shift)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in toEncode)
        {
            // Convert the character to its ASCII equivalent
            int curr = c;
            // Num could be either positive or negative
            curr += shift;

            /* Below we handle the case where there's a "wrap-around." Examples:
             * - Shift of 27 is equivalent to a shift of 1, for example
             * - Shifting "z" by 1 wraps it around to "a"
             */

            // If they wrapped around by shifting to the right (num is positive).
            // We could do something similar to this with Modular arithmetic too
            while (curr > 122)
                curr -= 26;
            // If they wrapped around by shifting to the left (num is negative).
            while (curr < 97)
                curr += 26;

            sb.Append((char)curr);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Here are the tests I ran on it:

```
Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("z", 2)); // b

            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 1)); // b
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 2)); // c
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 3)); // d
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 4)); // e
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 5)); // f
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 6)); // g
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 7)); // h
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 24)); // y
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 25)); // z
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 26)); // a (shift of 26 is equivalent to no shift)
            Console.WriteLine(cls.CaesarCypher("a", 27)); // b (shift of 27 is equivalent to a shift of 1)
```

Comment: Very good point about "you never use the value … which could either indicate a bug or incomplete code section." A good IDE or other static code analyzer would help catch that in most cases.

Comment: 122 and 97 are magic numbers. It's clearer to use the UTF-16 literal code units 'z' and 'a' than the UTF-16 integer code unit values.